# Xamarin executing a PHP file locally or online?

Tags: php, android, xamarin, hosting

Was trying to play around with my brothers on this app, the goal of making this app is just for fun, not going to achieve anything on the security aspect, nothing much.
The last thing that I want to achieve is that I want to call a php file from my app.

From the tutorial I watched on youtube, 
`HttpWebRequest.Create(string.Format(@"http://192.168.0.101/load.php"))`

This works fine as I call 'load.php' from my server(another machine on same network), then the file will establish the connection to an online database(freemysqlhosting), then the file will run some queries and display the return results on my app.

**So my question is, what if I want to call the load.php somewhere but not from my server ?**

Is it possible for the app to call the file directly from its directory ? Does app works in that way like php/c++ ?

Or must I buy some web hosting accounts to upload a single php file online so that my app can call it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should load the PHP file from a server.

If you want to load a web server inside your app, first you have to code (or include) the web server code and then include the PHP binaries in your app for the architecture of your app

Comment: What if the app is not on the same network as the server, it cant load the file right ? web server means online hosting(those that I have to pay?)

Comment: If the server is not in the same network, you have to use the public IP of your server , instead 192.168.x.x

Comment: That would give me 404 Not Found on my server machine and client machine. 60.xx.xx.xxx/load.php

Comment: Thank you so much, port forwarding does the last trick. Thank you once again taking time to help !!